# Document References query example

Tags: mongodb

If I choose to use [Document References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#model-one-to-many-relationships-with-document-references) with a structure of [Materialized Paths](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/#pattern) instead of the simple [Embedded Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#model-one-to-many-relationships-with-embedded-documents) how can I display the same results?

For example if I had Embedded docs I simply :

```
db.col.find({'user' : 'foo'})
```

and return:

```
{'user' : 'foo',
 'posts' : [ {}, 
             {},
             {} 
  ]
}
```

Which command should I use to display posts as an embedded array of that user? Or this can only happen client-side?

Comment: Could you please mention your materialized paths for user & posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's document references,

users collection will contain:

```
{
  _id : "foo",
  // users details
}
```

and posts collection:

```
{
   _id: "postid",
   author: "foo"
   // other fields
}
```

In this case,

1) First make query to get the user id from users collection.

2) Then send the user id to the posts collection to get all posts

```
var user = db.users.find({_id : "foo"});
```

// this is used to get user details or validate user and only after validation if you need to fetch the posts

```
var posts = db.posts.find({author:  user._id });
```

As the documents are referenced, there will be a roundtrip to the server which is obvious.

I am not sure how you have used materialized path for this scenario, let me know the data structure of it and i would be able to mention the query based on that.

Comment: I'm in schema development and want to be sure that denormalization would work ideally. Based on your example the path for the users would be `'path' : null` and for the posts of the user foo `'path': ',foo,'`. So in short this can only happen with rerouting (=client side in my mind) :) Thanks